# How to remove the default error handling in ConnectionRequest

Tags: codenameone

I want to use the Rest-class to do some http-calls, since it seems very convenient. However, I can not seem to use it together with custom error handling. Whatever I do, I am always meet with the built-in pop-up from the ConnectionRequest default implementation.

Since the interface to the Rest methods includes a

```
public interface Callback<T> extends SuccessCallback<T>, FailureCallback<T> {
}

// RequestBuilder.java
public void getAsStringAsync(final Callback<Response<String>> callback) {...}
```

it strikes me a bit odd, that I can not really utilize the FailureCallback, since it is never called due to the default popup in the default implementation in ConnectionRequest.

Am I misunderstanding how to use the FailureCallback in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Failure callback should be called regardless, there are some variants of this method that might have a problem with the callback code so if you have a specific method reference that isn't working I can take a look at that.

Regarding generic error handling. Funny thing, we just updated the default project created in the new project wizard to include such code so people will find it easily. See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-default-code.html

The code to override the default network handling error would look something like this:

```
addNetworkErrorListener(err -> { 
    // prevent the event from propagating
    err.consume();
    if(err.getError() != null) {
        Log.e(err.getError());
    }
    Log.sendLogAsync();
});
```

Notice that the code needs a CN class static import to compile:

```
import static com.codename1.ui.CN.*;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Neither 
`getAsJsonMap(final SuccessCallback<Response<Map>> callback, final FailureCallback<? extends Object> onError)` seems to be the only method where `bindOnError` is called and hence the only method where the Failure callback is actually registered.

Comment: I think I remember this now. The original implementation ignored `onFailure` and I made a mental note to fix that. I was concerned that a fix would break compatibility so I left it for later. It should be easy to fix for the most part just changing calls like `getAsJsonMap(callback, null);` to `getAsJsonMap(callback, callback);`. Can you please file an issue? We'll try to address it after the release.